# Titanium: Paint module for android 2.2

Tags: android, module, titanium

I download Paint module in market place (Ti.Paint Android version 2.0.1), and I run it on Emulator Android 2.3. It is OK. 
BUT when I run on Emulator Android 2.2(Froyo). It's ERROR: Requested module not found: ti.paint. 
What is version of Paint module which run on Android 2.2 and Android 2.3? 
Or how can I run Paint module on android 2.2, 2.3?

Thanks, Hiep

Info: Application type: mobile Titanium SDK: 
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 2.0.2 Platform & version: Android 2.2, 2.3 Device: Android emulator Host Operating System: Windows XP Titanium Studio: Titanium Studio, build: 2.0.2.201205311912

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I think I got ERR because I was not CLEAN my project before I run since I got that ERR.